# Is it possible to subtract one voltage from another without the use of an op-amp?

Tags: operational-amplifier, history

I've been watching a video on the early techniques used to create truly flat surfaces for precision engineering, and started wondering when it would first have been possible to develop an [LVDT](https://www.omega.co.uk/technical-learning/linear-variable-displacement-transducers.html) for measuring displacement.

The reading is the difference between the two vOut, meaning a subtraction is required.

Would this have been possible without an op-amp? And if so, how?

Comment: Realize that an op-amp is a *functional description* not an *implementation*.  And no, it is not the only form of *differential amplifier*.

Comment: Placing two voltage sources in series but reversing one of them is a form of subtraction. Vacuum tubes also exist.

Comment: http://www.philbrickarchive.org/k2-w_refurbished.pdf

Comment: At least as far back as magnetic meter movements

Comment: @Toor How would you achieve that with two voltages relative to the same ground? ChrisStratton - You're quite right, I _was_ thinking of it incorrectly

Comment: You wouldn't :D. It's not obviously not a universal approach. But you could use a floating or battery powered measurement that isn't relative to that same ground which starts to meandre into the magnetic meter movements that @sstobbe mentioned.

Comment: relays can switch between inputs, say at 100 hz. then the output is amplified. Silence means equality.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

LVDT, a differential transformer, has AC output.

It's easy to subtract AC signals, if they're produced by one 60Hz source, and coming from two separate (electrically floating) transformer windings.  (Just connect the two outputs in seires.)

Also, a Wheatstone bridge is the device for performing the subtraction.  Just use AC drive and AC meters, rather than DC.